# Parse xml with libxml2 and get named string value with C

Tags: c, xml, libxml2

I am very new to XML stuff, so i have to ask for help.
I have a xml file like this:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' standalone='yes' ?>
<main>
<string name="firstname">John2</string>
<string name="secondname">Doe</string>
<string name="Street">4th</string>
<string name="City">NY</string>
</main>
```

I have libxml2 and i need to get the `firstname`and the `lastname` values.
There are many examples, but i could not find how to get a node value by its name.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of

```
void getReference (xmlDocPtr doc, xmlNodePtr cur) {

    xmlChar *uri;
    cur = cur->xmlChildrenNode;
    while (cur != NULL) {
        if ((!xmlStrcmp(cur->name, (const xmlChar *)"reference"))) {
           1 uri = xmlGetProp(cur, "uri");
            printf("uri: %s\n", uri);
            xmlFree(uri);
        }
        cur = cur->next;
    }
    return;
}
```

Where cur would be your node "main" and the child attributes will come from using xmlGetProp function

Answer (score 0):

I don't know who minuses my question and why, but i have found the answer myself.

```
while (cur != NULL) {
    if ((!xmlStrcmp(cur->name, (const xmlChar *)"string"))) {
        uri = xmlGetProp(cur, "name");
        if ( ( !xmlStrcmp ( uri, ( const xmlChar * ) "firstname" ) ) ){
            key = xmlNodeListGetString ( doc, cur -> xmlChildrenNode,1);
            printf("string: %s\n", uri);
            printf ( "firstname: %s\n", key);
        }
       .... so on with the lastname
    }
    cur = cur->next;
}
```

Comment: I think I answered the question and the main thing was xmlGetProp

Comment: If you test it with my XML you will see if you have answered.